# Receiving strings, numbers, and images from Parse Sever and adding them to local arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am new to coding and I am trying to locate, retrieve, and append values from parse server to local arrays. Via a query, I am successfully able to retrieve all information and append it to my arrays in ViewDidLoad() **within my for in loop**. However, when I print the items of the array after running the query & for in loop, my arrays all contain nil, and not the values that were previously added.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
   query.whereKey("Bar", equalTo: BarText!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects,error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
        if let returnedobjects = objects {
            for object in returnedobjects {
                let postImageFile = object["PostImage"] as? PFFileObject

                postImageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.PickedBarImagePostArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
                    } else {
                        print("nothing")
                    }
                })
                let userProfilePicFile = object["ProfileImage"] as?
                PFFileObject
                userProfilePicFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.PickedBarPostProfileImageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
                    } else {
                        print("nothing")
                    }
                })

                self.PickedBarPostLikesArray.append((object["Likes"] as? Int)!)
                self.PickedBarPostUsernameArray.append((object["Username"] as? String)!)
                self.PickedBarPostTimeArray.append((object["UserTime"] as? String)!)
                self.PickedBarChekcedInArray.append((object["Checked"]as? String)!)
                self.PickedBarContentPostArray.append((object["ContentPost"] as? String)!)
                self.PickedBarPostArray.append((object["PostType"] as? String)!)
                print(self.PickedBarPostLikesArray)
                print(self.PickedBarPostUsernameArray)
                print(self.PickedBarPostTimeArray)
                print(self.PickedBarChekcedInArray)
                print(self.PickedBarContentPostArray)
                print(self.PickedBarPostArray)
            }
        }
    }
})
    print(self.PickedBarPostLikesArray)
    print(self.PickedBarPostUsernameArray)
    print(self.PickedBarPostTimeArray)
    print(self.PickedBarChekcedInArray)
    print(self.PickedBarContentPostArray)
    print(self.PickedBarPostArray)
    self.BarSelectedTableView.reloadData()

}
```

I get this in the console:

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[10]

["magellan"]

["5:59 P.M."]

["\"\""]

["\"\""]

[This is my Parse Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkBG6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your reload code is getting called before completion closure.
Put reload code inside closure
try this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 query.whereKey("Bar", equalTo: BarText!)
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects,error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
    if let returnedobjects = objects {
        for object in returnedobjects {
            let postImageFile = object["PostImage"] as? PFFileObject

            postImageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.PickedBarImagePostArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
                } else {
                    print("nothing")
                }
            })
            let userProfilePicFile = object["ProfileImage"] as?
            PFFileObject
            userProfilePicFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.PickedBarPostProfileImageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
                } else {
                    print("nothing")
                }
            })

            self.PickedBarPostLikesArray.append((object["Likes"] as? Int)!)
            self.PickedBarPostUsernameArray.append((object["Username"] as? String)!)
            self.PickedBarPostTimeArray.append((object["UserTime"] as? String)!)
            self.PickedBarChekcedInArray.append((object["Checked"]as? String)!)
            self.PickedBarContentPostArray.append((object["ContentPost"] as? String)!)
            self.PickedBarPostArray.append((object["PostType"] as? String)!)

           self.Reload()

        }
    }
}

 })



}

  func Reload(){

   self.BarSelectedTableView.reloadData()
  print(self.PickedBarPostLikesArray)
print(self.PickedBarPostUsernameArray)
print(self.PickedBarPostTimeArray)
print(self.PickedBarChekcedInArray)
print(self.PickedBarContentPostArray)
print(self.PickedBarPostArray)


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work by creating a button called "Refresh." Everything works appropriately. However, I would like to have the information fill the array's upon initial view as opposed to pressing a button. Can anyone explain why this occurs?

Comment: I might want to open a new issue for this with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Its because reload code is getting called before completion closure.